# Xlsxwriter, Dynamically add multiple series to column chart

Tags: python, pandas, charts, xlsxwriter

Found solution to my question.  Create a range for the first and last column and then loop through the range.

'''
# add a line for qtr rates by type
# Create a new chart object.
chart3 = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'line'})

```
# set the range for the number of columns that are sub types
type_range = range(0,8) 

# loop through list of sub type numbedrs
for t in type_range:  

    # Add a series to the chart.
    chart3.add_series({
                            'name':  '=Qtr_Type_Rate!$' +  col_alpha(type_pivot.shape[1]-t) + '$3',
                            'categories': '=Qtr_Type_Rate!$B$4:$B$' + str(type_pivot.shape[0] + 3), 
                            'values': '=Qtr_Type_Rate!$' + col_alpha(type_pivot.shape[1]-t) + '$4:$' + col_alpha(type_pivot.shape[1]-t) +  '$' + str(type_pivot.shape[0] + 3),
                        })


# Add a chart title and some axis labels.
chart3.set_title ({'name': 'Quarterly Incident Rate per 100 Employees by Type,  Between ' + str(min_fisc) + '-' + str(max_fisc)})
chart3.set_x_axis({'name': 'Fiscal'})
chart3.set_y_axis({'name': 'Rates'})

# place the charte
worksheet3.insert_chart(
                            col_beta(type_pivot.shape[1]) + '3', 
                            chart3
                        )
```

'''

I have a dataframe that is added to the Excel tab that will have changing columns over time.  From this I am producing a column chart.  Each of the changing columns will be a new series added to the chart.

Current I have to add or remove the "chart1.add_series({})" to match the columns in the dataframe

Can I loop through the columns and produce a new "chart1.add_series({})" for each column?  - and if "yes", any examples would be helpful.

thanks

Eg.

```
    for col in df.columns:
        chart1.add_series({
                            'name':  '=Totals_FY!$' + col_alpha(types_pivot.shape[1] - 1) + '$3',
                            'categories': '=Totals_FY!$B$4:$B$' + str(types_pivot.shape[0] + 3), 
                            'values': '=Totals_FY!$' + col_alpha(types_pivot.shape[1] - 1) + '$4:$' + col_alpha(types_pivot.shape[1] -1) +  '$' + str(types_pivot.shape[0] + 3),
                            'data_labels':{
                                            'value':True,
                                            'category_name':True,
                                            'position':'outside_end'
                                            }
                        })
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do but you have all columns as `df.columns` and you can use it with `for`-loop.

Comment: So what I want to do is loop through the columns and produce a new series in the chart: